# Overflow menu button not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have some fragments and an activity in my application(Min sdk = 8 and target sdk = 11)
The problem is with menu button, when I go to Fragments part it shows me the overflow menu icon in top right of action bar, but in activity part I can see the action bar but overflow menu is not coming.

I am checking it on tablet having android 4.0.4 version, It doesn't have any hardware menu button.

Any idea where I might be doing something wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/start" android:title="@string/start" />
<item android:id="@+id/stop" android:title="Stop" />

/>
</menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "go to Fragments part"? And can you show your menu XML?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have added my menu.xml, actually there are two buttons where one is moving me on activity screen and other is moving to the fragments screen.

Comment: I still don't understand. You're saying there are different screens for the activity and the fragment? A fragment is shown as part of an activity, so I don't understand the distinction. Maybe screenshots will help.

Comment: @skygeek Can you please tell me how you resolve the issue, i am facing the same in 4.0.4.